# Get New Line without Losing Text

Tags: swift, uitextview

I've got a text view and I want to add a button that when clicked creates a new line. I've tried things like \r and \r\n, but both delete what is currently in the text view. I want to be able to create a new line without having the current text in the view deleted. This is what I've got so far:

```
@IBAction func line(sender: AnyObject) {
    textView.text = "\r"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the previously added text as well:

```
textView.text = textView.text + "\n"
```